# How to export a channel from multi-channel EXR image using OpenEXR

Tags: python, openexr

I have EXR image containing the multiple image channels like `cryptomatte`, `reflect`, `refract`, `specular` and etc. I would like to go ahead and export these embedded channels as separate PNG or JPG images. Both OpenEXR and OpenEXR Python module are installed, the EXR file can be read from inside of Python:

```
import OpenEXR
file = OpenEXR.InputFile('/home/my-exr-image.exr')
dw = file.header()['dataWindow']
sz = (dw.max.x - dw.min.x + 1, dw.max.y - dw.min.y + 1)
```

What commands should be used to export the `reflect` channel as a separate PNG image?